# Wordpress Plugin or Code in function.php?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I always see it said that the less plugins you use, the better the performance of the site, but what about those plugins that deactivate native functions with the idea of ​​optimizing performance?

Is it better to use a simple wordpress plugin to remove the blog like [Disable Blog By Joshua Nelson](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-blog/) or use your own code in the functions.php of the child theme?

uptade:

I found this code that disables the features of the blog in the backend, it met in a few lines my need to hide the blog

```
<?php
// Disable Default Post Type

    // Turn default post type inacessible in backend
    function remove_default_post_type($args, $postType) {
        if ($postType === 'post') {
            $args['public']                = false;
            $args['show_ui']               = false;
            $args['show_in_menu']          = false;
            $args['show_in_admin_bar']     = false;
            $args['show_in_nav_menus']     = false;
            $args['can_export']            = false;
            $args['has_archive']           = false;
            $args['exclude_from_search']   = true;
            $args['publicly_queryable']    = false;
            $args['show_in_rest']          = false;
        }

        return $args;
    }
    add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'remove_default_post_type', 0, 2);
// End remove post type
```

Comment: The actual number of active plugins on a site isn't nearly as important as the quality of the plugins. If you have 100 well-written plugins active, that's better than terrible plugins. Typically, single-function tasks that solve one issue for you are just fine to use.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on preference and how technical you are with WordPress functions and code. You know your code and if you think some few lines of code in functions.php can achieve your purpose I see no need to install a new plugin.

Comment: Got it, I'm a beginner and I'm trying to learn and improve the sites I create in wordpress, maybe for now the most appropriate thing will be to use plugins, thanks